# All test cases passed in junit but PIT is failing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, pitest

While running pit and jacoco, all test cases are passed and jacoco coverage is fine, but PIT mutation test is failing with below error.

```
Build Failure
All tests did not pass without mutation when calculating line coverage. Mutation testing requires a green suite.
```

Since all my test cases are passed, i am not able to figure it out why PIT test is failing. I don't see any test failures in the console while running PIT test.

Please suggest how to find which test case is failing in PIT if that is the case, if not please let me know what could be the reason behind PIT test failure.

Comment: According to the following site, there would be an output report somewhere that might include the details: https://gradle-pitest-plugin.solidsoft.info/ ${PROJECT_DIR}/build/reports/pitest

Comment: Output report will be generated for PIT test if it fails also?

Comment: If yes, then where can I find the report in maven-pitest?

Comment: Best way to find out for your test setup is to run the test again and look for the output in that directory I posted.

Comment: Ours is maven project

Comment: There is a guide for maven: https://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/ section POM Configuration.

Answer (score 2):

When I inject a fault into my test suite and run Pitest, then it clearly shows me which tests fail. Even without enabling "verbose" logging.

I have configured Pitest in my `pom.xml` in order to add some configuration for my tests to run properly. The following block might be in the `<pluginManagement>` section or in a `<profile>`:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.16</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Now I can run `mvn test-compile pitest:mutationCoverage` on command line to run my (faulty) test suite without the regular unit testing.

In the console output of Pitest I can see which test methods fail:

```
22:54:05 PIT >> INFO : Verbose logging is disabled. If you encounter a problem,
please enable it before reporting an issue.
22:54:06 PIT >> INFO : Incremental analysis reduced number of mutations by 0
22:54:06 PIT >> INFO : Created  69 mutation test units in pre scan
22:54:07 PIT >> INFO : Sending 85 test classes to minion
22:54:07 PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
|22:54:17 PIT >> SEVERE : Description [testClass=com.myproject.core.MyTestClass,
  name=[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:com.myproject.core.MyTestClass]/[method:testBrokenOne()]]
  did not pass without mutation.
/22:54:17 PIT >> SEVERE : Description [testClass=com.myproject.core.MyTestClass,
  name=[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:com.myproject.core.MyTestClass]/[method:testMethodTwo()]]
  did not pass without mutation.
|22:54:19 PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 13 seconds.
22:54:19 PIT >> SEVERE : Tests failing without mutation:
Description [testClass=com.myproject.core.MyTestClass,
  name=[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:com.myproject.core.MyTestClass]/[method:testMethodOne()]]
Description [testClass=com.myproject.core.MyTestClass,
  name=[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:com.myproject.core.MyTestClass]/[method:testMethodTwo()]]
```

*(Added linebreaks for readability)*

So I see that `MyTestClass.testMethodOne()` and `MyTestClass.testMethodTwo()` fail to run even without mutation.

When I add `-Dverbose=true` on the command line, I find there the output of the test framework which is like:

```
23:07:37 PIT >> INFO : MINION : org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <25> but was: <24>
```

To narrow it further down if needed, you might want to limit each test method to a single `assert` statement. And you can add logging (to console or file) to check the variables of your tests.

The reason might be a parameter (maybe you specify some property on command line or in the pom?) that your regular tests get but not when started by Pitest. I myself learned just recently that Pitest spawns new jvm instances that need to get parameters transferred via `<jvmArgs>` in some cases.